# Bounding the absolute value of expectation and median of a random variable

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, upper-lower-bounds

If $$P(|X-M|) >t ) \leq a\exp(\frac{-t^2}{b})$$ how can I show that absolute value of the median and expectation is bounded by

$$|M – EX| \leq \min \Big(\sqrt(ab), \frac{a\sqrt(b\pi)}{2}\Big)$$ where $M$ is the median and $t > 0$ and $a,b$ are positive constants.

Comment: At a minimum we are assuming $\mathbb E[|X|]<\infty$...are we also assuming that $X$ has a unique median?

Comment: Integrate that what you are given over $[0,\infty)$ (with respect to $t$).

Comment: @amsmath, you mean integrate the first equation w.r.to t, and we will get the result ?.

Comment: Yep, exactly... Well, at least one of the two estimates.

Comment: @amsmath, how can I integrate the term P(|X-M|)>t) w.r.t t ?. X is the r.v ?.

Comment: I guess the cdf is absolutely continuous. Then you can work with densities.

Comment: You have$$\frac a 2 \sqrt{b\pi}\ge\int_0^\infty\int_t^\infty f_Y(x)\,dx\,dt,$$where $f_Y$ is the density of $Y:=|X-M|$. Now use Fubini and use that $E(Y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty xf_Y(x)\,dx$ and $|M-EX| = |E(M-X)|\le E(Y)$.

Comment: @amsmath  How do you conclude that  $$\int_t^\infty dt = x$$. Similarly, how can we conclude that  $$|M – EX| \leq \sqrt(ab)$$

Comment: Your integral does not make sense. Also I wrote: use Fubini (correctly). You cannot just swap the integrals. As I wrote, $\int_t^\infty\,dt$ does not make any sense. When you want to swap integrals, you have to adapt the bounds. As to your last question, I don't know. But please use MathJax properly. You should write \sqrt{ab}.